# Javascript form POST to website does not recognize my session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

Using JavaScript I would like to automate the submission of data via a form POST to a website that requires a login. Using a browser, I am able to login to this site and create a session. On another tab of the same browser, I would like to open up a second tab on the same browser and load the page where my JavaScript resides and allow the JavaScript code to interact with the website session I created on the first tab so the data being posted is admitted as the session I am logged on from the first tab.

The purpose of this is to automate the posting of data to this website that requires login.
I have the JS that does my form POST automation. However the issue I am encountering is that the JS fails to post to the website because it does not seem to detect or use the session information from the previous tab and therefore thinks I am not logged in.

In short, how can I allow the Javascript http request running in one tab of my browser interact and take advantage of a session I have created with another website I have logged in in another tab of the same browser?

Comment: if the session cookies are set correctly (cookie path + cookie domain in particular), JS should't have to do ANYTHING for them to work properly.

Comment: Is YOUR page on the same domain as the other page that you want to post to? Or does that page allow cross site requests via CORS headers for your domain? If not, you cannot use Javascript on a different domain in a browser to post. And it is not because of the session cookie, but because of the general Javascript security rules.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Sven, the page that hosts the JS is not on the same server as where I want to submit the data. The JS code, for all that matters, could just be a page i have on my local computer. I want to POST To the external website.

Marc B, I think that may be what I am doing wrong with the JS XMLHttpRequest send command. I may not be including the cookie information.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i needed to add the withCredentials property to the xmlHttpRequest. Doing this allowed me to impersonate the cookies i already had set on the other tab.